# How can I check from the frontend if a dropdown is empty to not show it?

Tags: python, html, django

I was seeing this could be achieved using AJAX, but I'm not very familiar with it and I'm not sure how to approach it since my html is limited.

I have a form, which has ForeignKey dependent dropdowns. Some of the options in the first dropdown cause the second to not have any options, in which case I'd like for it to not appear, without having to refresh the page.

My page has an ajax request from a tutorial on how to make these dependent dropdowns, but I couldn't figure out how to create a request to check whether **station_number** is empty or not, to maybe hide/unhide from the div, or something of that sort, not sure what's possible

**enter_exit_area.html**

```
{% block main %}
    <form id="warehouseForm" action="" method="POST" data-stations-url="{% url 'operations:ajax_load_stations' %}" novalidate >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div>
            <div>
                {{ form.adp_number.help_text }}
                {{ form.adp_number }}
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ form.work_area.help_text }}
                {{ form.work_area }}
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ form.station_number.help_text }}
                {{ form.station_number }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" name="enter_area" value="Enter">Enter Area</button>
                <button type="submit" name="leave_area" value="Leave">Leave Area</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#id_work_area").change(function () {
            var url = $("#warehouseForm").attr("data-stations-url");
            var workAreaId = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: {
                    'work_area': workAreaId
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#id_station_number").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
     </script>
{% endblock main %}
```

also including **load_stations** from my views.py in case it's helpful in any way.

```
def load_stations(request):
    work_area_id = request.GET.get('work_area')
    stations = StationNumber.objects.filter(work_area_id=work_area_id).order_by('name')
    return render(request, 'operations/station_number_dropdown_options.html', {'stations': stations})
```

**station_number_dropdown_options.html**

```
<option value="">---------</option>
{% for station in stations %}
<option value="{{ station.pk }}">{{ station.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: can you post your `operations/station_number_dropdown_options.html` code as well?, I presume it is just the `<option ..>` items that goes into the select, but it will help to clarify this.

Comment: @gabriel just added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As code shown, you can modify your JS as follows:

```js
$("#id_work_area").change(function () {
    var url = $("#warehouseForm").attr("data-stations-url");
    var workAreaId = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {
            'work_area': workAreaId
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#id_station_number").html(data);
            // Check the length of the options child elements of the select
            if ($("#id_station_number option").length == 1) {
                $("#id_station_number").parent().hide(); // hide parent of the <select node (as your code, the <div> containing the input and the help_text)
            } else {
                // If any option, ensure the select is shown
                $("#id_station_number").parent().show();
            }
        }
     });
});
```

As you can see, checking the length of the options inside the desired select should do the trick.

The else statement will show the select again if any option is present when the user changes de related warehouse value.

---

**Some considerations**

- You can avoid the creation of `<option value="">---------</option>` using a `forloop.first` if statement into your `station_number_dropdown_options.html`, if you do so, you must change the check of the length of the `<option` element to 0 instead of 1 in the JavaScript
- Evaluate to use `class Media` in your form to include it's related scripts (and css if needed), docs here -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/media/)

hope this helps you